# Keeping up with our progress on Area 51. Keep the good questions coming!

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

The Area 51 site has various metrics by which the stack overflow teams assesses the viability and growth of our community (our site profile can be found [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16617/academia)).

After the flurry of initial questions asked by several key members of the community, it appears the rate of questions asked has decreased some. So this question is just a guise to prompt the community to *ask good questions*, which will allow the site to continue to grow.

So get out there and contribute with both answers *and good questions*!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of those initial questions were mine, so it was kind of artificially inflated... we're probably settling down to steady state now.

However, this question is a great time to bring back up the topic of [promoting the site](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24/73). We haven't made an official poster, but please post links to the site anywhere and everywhere!

Comment: Good point about promotion. And thank you for all of the work that went into your questions. It very effectively set the tone and helped define the scope of the site.

Comment: Agreed. As far as I can tell, the number of questions is borderline worrying, but our traffic is downright bad. Solving the latter issue will certainly lead to increasing the number of (hopefully good) questions.