# Publicity Poster

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I was browsing through the Meta questions and among other things, a publicity poster seemed to be appearing a lot.

[This](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24/publicizing-the-site) question seemed to have a lot of poster suggestions.

Eynakal had a sample poster as an answer to a [Meta Question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24/publicizing-the-site/87#87). The link to his poster is [here](http://erikdev.com/AcaSx.pdf).

I thought of putting forth my creation.

[image: Academia.SE Poster]

A few points:

1. I sorted questions by votes and simply chose the ones that (I felt) appealed to a greater audience.
2. I created this in 2 hours so it has many rough edges. The reason I am putting it up now is to get (constructive) criticism on it (or hints that it is too bad and drop it).
3. I don't care about copyrights and credits and I'll gladly give away the `XCF` (GIMP) file to whoever is interested. I'll put it up on github or something.
4. The reason I created this as a separate question rather than answering the one above is to allow for a dedicated question (maybe community wiki?) for all poster designs.

Comment: I think this poster is very dark and would be hard to print.

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev, I assumed that people have access only to BnW printers; Black text over White Background seems a little boring for my taste. But, you have a perfectly valid point. I'll try to fix the colors.

Comment: I agree with @Arteem; the white on black is very hard on printers. The layout is nice, though... I would suggest using a white/gray/bold black color scheme for simplicity.

Comment: What is the point of this "design?" Where do you plan on posting it? Print or online only? I am a professional designer that can give a lot of feedback if you give me more insight to what the goal and specs are. Right now it is pretty bad for a number of reasons.

Comment: @Ryan. I didn't have an intention of use per se. Just started off making it as it came to me. I'd love to hear your criticism.